# Query is TRUE when its not

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

Please be gentle with me i have just recently trying to learn PHP/SQL.

The problem is that the first query is ALWAYS TRUE when it shouldn't (base on what i know).

The query simply state to get the 'username' where betakey=$betakey provided by user. The fact that my datebase columns is still empty except column betakey doesn't make that query statement true at all.

Please help, maybe i am missing some knowledge on this.

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

$firstName = $_GET['rfirstname'];
$lastName = $_GET['rlastname'];
$username = $_GET['rusername'];
$password = $_GET['rpass'];
$betakey = $_GET['rkey'];

$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$db_username="**"; // Mysql username 
$db_password="**"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="**"; // Database name 


$conn = mysqli_connect("$host", "$db_username", "$db_password","$db_name");

if (!$conn){
die ("Error: ".mysqli_connect_error());
}

$query1 = "SELECT username='$username' FROM users2 WHERE betakey='$betakey';";
$result_1 = mysqli_query($conn,$query1);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result_1) > 0){ 

echo 'Beta key is used';

}else{

$query2 = "UPDATE users2 SET firstName='$firstName',lastName='$lastName',username='$username',password='$password' WHERE betakey='$betakey'";

echo 'Registration Successful';
} 

mysqli_close($conn);//Close off the MySQL connection to save resources.
?>
```

Comment: Your first query should only be `SELECT username FROM users2 WHERE betakey='$betakey';`

Comment: Besides the typo made in the query; that code is so unsafe and dangerous, it almost scares me.

Comment: You also never executed the update query, so that too qualifies as a typographical error.

Comment: @ catcon, i already tried that query and its still the same result.. a little follow up, i tried to run the query in sql and the result was the username column but is blank. That does count as a mysqli_num_rows count?,

Answer (score 1):

You have plenty of problems in your code. Let me help you fix some of them

- You should learn [how to properly open mysqli connection](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/mysqli_connect). You need to enable error reporting and set the correct charset.
- You should never concatenate PHP variables into SQL query. Always use [parameterized **prepared statements**](https://phpdelusions.net/MySQLi) instead of manually building your queries.
- Your first SQL query has an error. `username='$username'` is meaningless and wrong. If all you want to do is [check existence use `COUNT(1)`](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/check_value) or something similar.

Here is my take on your fixed code:

```
<?php

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

$firstName = $_GET['rfirstname'];
$lastName = $_GET['rlastname'];
$username = $_GET['rusername'];
$password = $_GET['rpass'];
$betakey = $_GET['rkey'];

$host = "localhost"; // Host name
$db_username = "**"; // Mysql username
$db_password = "**"; // Mysql password
$db_name = "**"; // Database name

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$conn = new mysqli($host, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name);
$conn->set_charset('utf8mb4');

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(username) FROM users2 WHERE betakey=?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $_GET['rusername']);
$stmt->execute();
$result_1 = $stmt->get_result();
$used = $result_1->fetch_row()[0];

if ($used) {
    echo 'Beta key is used';
} else {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE users2 SET firstName=?, lastName=?, username=?, password=? WHERE betakey=?");
    $stmt->bind_param('sssss', $firstName, $lastName, $username, $password, $betakey);
    $stmt->execute();

    echo 'Registration Successful';
}
```